# Which pluck is used in Cheap Thrills?

Tags: sound-design, vst, replication

Which pluck did they use in Sias' Cheap Thrills?

Or how could one get a similar sound? Is it maybe included in a VST you can purchase?

Answer (score 2):

It also depends on what DAW you use.

[image: DX10]

In FL studio, you can try with Fruity DX10.

[image: pluck ableton]

In Ableton, you can search pluck sound from top search box.

To make it sounds similar as Cheap Thrills pluck, you might need a little high cut on the sound and add stereo reverb on that.

There are a lot of pluck sounds which come with third party plugins such as Nexus, slynth2, Hypersonic2, Massive and Serum.

If you would prefer sampling, you can pick Cheap Thrills pluck as a sample and load into Ableton sampler or whatever sampler plugin you like.

Check out this tutorial which is remaking cheap thrills track.

Comment: How would I do it with Fruity DX10? Is it a sampler?

Comment: Nope, it's not a sampler. If you want a sampler in FL, you can use Fruity slicer and sampler. 
Actually, FL has a plugin called "plucked" but It just come with two knobs. If you want to control the release, decay and attack stuffs, it might be difficult. 

That's why I recommend you to use DX10. In DX10, You can also browse the presets with a little arrow at the top-left corner and play with it.  
To make it sounds pluck, you can tweak decay to around 10 o'clock, make your piano notes short and add a stereo reverb/delay.